# text falls to new line even though div has available width to grow

Tags: css

I have a div which will eventually has only text content inside it and i want it to has width equal to content if it's not wider than 150px.
What i mean is that if it has short text inside it, it will have width of fit-content, but if it has long text inside that will exceed max-width, i want that text to fall to new line while keeping max-width. For long text my div is working as expected but for short text second word always falls to new line even if there is available width.

This is the styling of my div,

stylings of div: https://i.stack.imgur.com/puENu.png

3 sample pics of results:

- short text: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkIAK.png
- medium text: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiNxh.png
- long text:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYSwl.png

Thank you for any kind of your help in advance.